# yarn add all, yarn install, npm install; none of these commands are working for me while I'm using Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, yarnpkg, node-gyp

I've been trying to execute the commands
`npm install`, `yarn install`, `yarn add all` but no command works for me. I know that `yarn`  is installed for me when I execute `npm install yarn`. Node.js is also installed in the latest version v16.13.2 and latest VS Code v1.63.2 system set up.

Here are the errors that appear :

- `yarn install`

  ```
  PS C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5> yarn install
  yarn install v1.22.17
  warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
  warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by t
  ools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoi
  d resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this
  warning, remove package-lock.json.
  [1/4] Resolving packages...
  [2/4] Fetching packages...
  [3/4] Linking dependencies...
  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
  error C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules
  \canvas: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
  Arguments:
  Directory: C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_mo
  dules\canvas
  Output:
  node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
  node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | ia32
  node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_eng
  ine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" (not found)
  node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/downloa
  d/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz
  node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Au
  tomattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-win32-unkno
  wn-ia32.tar.gz
  node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@1
  6.13.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
  node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/
  Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-win32-unk
  nown-ia32.tar.gz
  gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
  gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | ia32
  gyp info ok
  gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
  gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | ia32
  gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.e
  xe"
  gyp ERR! find VS
  gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
  gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
  gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, t
  ry re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
  gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
  gyp ERR! find VS - not found
  gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
  gyp ERR! find VS
  gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
  gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
  gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
  gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
  gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
  gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
  gyp ERR! find VS
  gyp ERR! configure error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
  gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Ya
  rn\Data\global\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
  gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\MidouPC\
  AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:36
  3:14)
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
  gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
  gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
  gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MidouPC
  \\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
  "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\MidouPC\\Downloads\\hashl
  ips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node
  " "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\MidouPC\\Downloads\\hashlips_
  art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version
  =8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"




  gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_
  modules\canvas
  gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
  gyp ERR! not ok
  node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallb
  ack-to-build --module=C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch
  _v5\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_
  path=C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\
  canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=
  0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MidouPC\Downlo
  ads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\uti
  l\compile.js:89:23)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:interna
  l/child_process:301:5)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
  node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users
  \\MidouPC\\Downloads\\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\\node_modules\\@mapbox\
  \node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
  node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch
  _v5\node_modules\canvas
  node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
  node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
  node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
  Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\
  MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\canvas\build\R
  elease\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads
  \hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_ver
  sion=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (
  1)
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this
  command.

  PS C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5>
  ```
- `npm install`

  ```
  PS C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5> npm install

  up to date, audited 66 packages in 2s

  6 packages are looking for funding
    run `npm fund` for details

  4 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 1 high)

  To address all issues, run:
    npm audit fix

  Run `npm audit` for details.
  PS C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5>
  ```

  It shows like it was successfully executed but when I run `node index.js`.
- `yarn add all`

  ```
  yarn add v1.22.17
  warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
  warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by t
  ools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoi
  d resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this
  warning, remove package-lock.json.
  [1/4] Resolving packages...
  [2/4] Fetching packages...
  [3/4] Linking dependencies...
  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
  error C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules
  \canvas: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
  Arguments:
  Directory: C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_mo
  dules\canvas
  Output:
  node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
  node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | ia32
  node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_eng
  ine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" (not found)
  node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/downloa
  d/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz
  node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Au
  tomattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-win32-unkno
  wn-ia32.tar.gz
  node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@1
  6.13.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
  node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/
  Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v93-win32-unk
  nown-ia32.tar.gz
  gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
  gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | ia32
  gyp info ok
  gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
  gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | ia32
  gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Python310\python.e
  xe"
  gyp ERR! find VS
  gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
  gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
  gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, t
  ry re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
  gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
  gyp ERR! find VS - not found
  gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
  gyp ERR! find VS
  gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
  gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
  gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
  gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
  gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
  gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
  gyp ERR! find VS
  gyp ERR! configure error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
  gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Ya
  rn\Data\global\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
  gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\MidouPC\
  AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:36
  3:14)
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
  gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\MidouPC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modul
  es\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
  gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
  gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
  gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MidouPC
  \\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
  "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\MidouPC\\Downloads\\hashl
  ips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node
  " "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\MidouPC\\Downloads\\hashlips_
  art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version
  =8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"

  gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_
  modules\canvas
  gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
  gyp ERR! not ok
  node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallb
  ack-to-build --module=C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch
  _v5\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_
  path=C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\
  canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=
  0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MidouPC\Downlo
  ads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\uti
  l\compile.js:89:23)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:interna
  l/child_process:301:5)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
  node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users
  \\MidouPC\\Downloads\\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\\node_modules\\@mapbox\
  \node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
  node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch
  _v5\node_modules\canvas
  node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
  node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
  node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
  Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\
  MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\canvas\build\R
  elease\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads
  \hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_ver
  sion=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (
  1)
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this comm
  and.
  PS C:\Users\MidouPC\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v5>
  ```

  Same results and same errors as `yarn install`.

I tried to install `node-gyp` and updated it but still not working and I also granted administrator use to VS Code, cmd doesn't work well and all these results are appearing in `powershell`.

I'm using an external terminal but when I use the integrated terminal the error stays the same only the message "install new vscode version/ newer" doesn't appear and also I've used Node.js v14 before that but it's totally not working.

Comment: please share your `package.json` content as well.